# How do I determine the host application of a pressed key using a global hook?

Tags: c#, winapi, com, hook, keyboard-hook

I'm interested in keyboard listening in the context of a particular application, like Microsoft Word. Googling showed that the only way to solve this problem is to use a global keyboard hook.

A global keyboard hook listens to *all* key press events in *all* active applications. For example, user types text in Microsoft Word (I need to catch these events) and simultaneously writes some messages to his friend on Facebook. This means my keyboard listener handles Facebook messages too, but this is excess information for me.

So my question is, how do I determine the host application of the last pressed key? Or in other words, how do I determine the current active application in order to understand the "context" of where a key was pressed?

Comment: You would need a global hook if you wanted to track key events that occurred in *any* application, but if you *only* need to interact with one single application like Microsoft Word, you would probably be better off using a Word-specific mechanism for this. For example, some kind of add-in that runs in the same context as Word and only receives events when Word does.

Comment: Maybe [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check if Microsoft Word is the active window. Then your keyboard listener can ignore all key presses if it is not the window the user is working on.

Comment: About "Word-specific mechanism" - I'm already developing COM addin but unfortunately there is no tools for developers to handle key press event. Google says - global keyboard hook or macro. But nobody answered to my previous question on stackoverflow about key listening with MS Word macro. Thats why I'm asking about global keyboard hook context. About GetForegroundWindow - thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: There is no need to install a global hook. You can install a thread hook for the thread that you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If the GetForegroundWindow idea doesn't work for you.  Since you already have a COM addin that loads with Word, [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), the last parameter lets you pass in a thread ID.  So inside your COM addin you can add a hook for every thread that Word uses, or from trial and error possibly figure out which thread you need to hook.  [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) (or DllEntryPoint) can be notified of all new threads, so that might be a good place to setup your hooks, and also release them.

Eventually anti-virus software might start to warn about these types of hooks, but so far the app I wrote that uses them has been installed on 100,000s of PCs, and we've had ZERO support calls of this nature.  Amazing as that is.